# android: display html pages when button clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation

FULLY UPDATED:

I have 100 html files. I know how to initialize the `<WebView />` for single xml page. But, If I used this method, then i need to create 100 xml pages. So, its waste of time.

So, I created `<WebView>` in `web.java` and 100 buttons in `chapters.java`

What i am asking is, if `button1` pressed, `chapter1.html` should be open in `web.java`. if `button2` pressed, `chapter2.html` should be open in `web.java`. like all 100 files should be open in `web.java` ?

My XML Code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:onClick="Button1"/>
```

.... 100 TextView

My JAVA code:

```
public void Button1(View v) {
WebView wv;  
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapter1.html"); 
}
```

.... 100 OnClick method.

Comment: @HossamOukli `webview cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: Do you have a webiew in your xml file?

Comment: Are you sure that you entered right name for layout?

Comment: Having 100 button on your Xml layout isn't a good idea, you may create them programmatically with java

Comment: i dunno how to create 100 buttons programmatically. can u help me pls

Comment: Check my update it's all there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in JAVA CODE. Just replace it with my code.

```
public void webClick(View v) 
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webview.class);
                intent.putExtra("weblink","file:///android_asset/chapter/chapter1.html");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

.
.
.
.
            default:
            break;
            }
         }
```

And create Webview.java with the following code;

```
public class Webview extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);; 
        String webLink = getIntent().getStringExtra("weblink");
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
        wv.loadUrl(webLink);

    }
```

So, for every call, your respective html file will be opened in the same browser. `Webview.java`. hope, it helps you. don't fail to mark this as answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as your textViews have no `Id`s

try to add this proprety `android:id="@+id/yourId"` to each of your textViews 
yourId will take values from `button1`  to `button5`

Use only one `onclick` method in all the textView:

then call each of them like that

```
void onclick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
    //Code will be executed when you click on Button1
    break;

    case R.id.button2:
    //Code will be executed when you click on Button2
    break;

    case R.id.button3:
    //Code will be executed when you click on Button3
    break;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    default:
    break;
    }
 }
```

**Update**

The following code worked fine for me:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="234dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="321dp"
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="224dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button [] myButton = new Button[100];
WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        myButton[i] = new Button(this);
        myButton[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton[i].setText("Button"+i);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton[i], i);

    }

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<myButton.length;i++)
    {
        if(myButton[i]==v)
        {
        String s=Integer.toString(i);
        wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapter1.html"+s);
        }

    }


}
}
```

Make sure you add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: i understand ur way. but can u pls type this with my code. (because i may do mistakes)

Comment: You need to make mistakes to learn from it, once the app crashes try to check your logCat , it will help to locate the source of your error, if you don't succed then post your logCat here we ll try to help.

Comment: sure. let me try this now;

Answer (score 0):

There is no WebView in your XML File . Add it . And take reference of that in the Oncreate only. Now u single WebView wv with all the methods.

```
      Public Class MainActivity extends Activity{
      WebView wv;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
      }
      }
```

Comment: still, it gives me an error. i dunno where to add webview in my xml ? help me out

Answer (score 0):

try this 
the loader page class:

```
    Package ...; //name of your package.
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class web extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

            WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enables java script

            mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
            mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

            mainWebView.loadUrl(" Your url "); // type your url here.
        }

        private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

           @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Xml file:

```
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/mainWebView">
 </WebView>
```

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
         ></uses-permission>
```

New code:  add this code in the Activity which sets the layout where your buttons are

```
    Button button15 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
           button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent p = new Intent (Activity.this,
                               Webds.class);

            }
        }
        );
}
```

webds class : add this

```
mWebview = new WebView(this);
mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
setContentView(mWebview);
```

Comment: it breaks if i tapped chapters button

Comment: what do you mean by breaks

Comment: i run the app in emulator, while clicking the chapters button, it breaks, and says Unfortunately, The App hasn't responding.

Comment: now added. but, if i used your code, html page has been opened directly when i clicked. wait let me update my question again

Comment: i mean if `button1` pressed, `chapter1.html` should be open in `web.java`. if `button2` pressed, `chapter2.html` should be open in `web.java`. like all 100 files should be open in `web.java` ?

Comment: it's simple you can do this by creating  a button in in java then load the url in onclick () functio

Comment: ok i am not sure because i have not tested it so i am editing my answere and try it then tell my if there is any problem..